# Graph nodes preserving changes to the overall graph

Tags: graph-theory, ds.data-structures, terminology

I remember reading about a kind of Graph data structure, where every change to the the graph could be preserved. I don't remember exactly neither the name, neither a good description (if it was the graph that remembered the changes, or each node who kept the changes of its childs).

It was on Wikipedia about 2-1.5 years ago, I was reading about version control. I would really appreciate if someone could help me find the name of this data sctructure.

---

Thanks Fraser, the paper is *[J. R. Driscoll, N. Sarnak, D. D. Sleator, R. E. Tarjan, Making Data Structures Persistent, Journal of Computer and System Sciences, Vol. 38, No. 1, 1989.](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/another-persistence.pdf)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of persistent data structures.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure

Comment: Thanks. The paper I was looking for is J. R. Driscoll, N. Sarnak, D. D. Sleator, R. E. Tarjan, Making Data Structures Persistent, Journal of Computer and System Sciences, Vol. 38, No. 1, 1989